# Piping from Istringstream into templates

Tags: c++, templates, istringstream

I have the following questions: I have a map from `string` to `string` which is called `psMap`. I.e. `psMap["a"]="20", psMap["b"]="test", psMap["c"]="12.5", psMap["d"]="1" (true)` so the map stores string-expressions of various basic-data types.

The following function `foo` should (given a key), copy the mapped value to a corresponding type variable, i.e;

```
int aa;
foo("a", aa); 
=> aa=20.
```

Explicitly, I want to have one function for all possible data-types (so no manually cast), so I tried with templates exploiting the automatic conversion of `istringsteram`, namely

```
template<class PARAMTYPE>
void foo(string _name, PARAMTYPE& _dataType) {
    PARAMTYPE buff;
    istringstream(psMap[_name]) >> buff;
    _dataType = buff;
}
```

The problem is, that the ">>" operation gives an error: `Error: no match for »operator>>« in »std::basic_stringstream<char>((* ....`

What is going wrong here? Does the `stringstream` not recognize the correct data type and tries to pipe into an abstract type of "template"? How could I make my code work?

Tank you for your effort :)

Comment: Dereference it to `>> *buf` and `*_dataType = *buff;`.

Comment: Don't you want istringstream rather than stringstream?

Comment: `buff`seems useless BTW, use `dataType` directly.

Comment: @ parkydr:sorry, corrected it

Answer (score 1):

You've created a temporary `std::istream`, which means that it
cannot bind to a non-const reference.  Some of the `>>` are
member functions, and they will work, but others are free
functions with the signature:

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&, TargetType& );
```

and these will not work (or even compile).

To avoid the problem either Just declare an `std::istringstream`
and use it, or call a member function on the temporary which
does nothing, but returns a (non-const) reference:

```
std::istringstream( psMap[name] ).ignore(0) >> buff;
```

(Personally, I find the separate variable more readable.)

Comment: For both versions I get an error for ambiguous overloading "for operator>>"

Comment: @Martin For what `PARAMTYPE`?

Answer (score 0):

You use reference as the template argument, so if you call

```
foo("a", aa);
```

without '`&` it should be fine (the way you tried the operator>> for pointer was needed). You also need to modify the last template line:

```
_dataType = buff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation:

```
template<class R>
R get_value(const std::string& name) {
    R result{};
    std::istringstream buffer{psMap[name]};
    buffer >> result;
    return result;
}
```

client code:

```
int x  = get_value<int>("a");
```

Also, do not use identifiers starting with an underscore. That is reserved for library implementers.

Comment: Re identifiers starting with an underscore: no.  Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a lower case are only reserved at global scope.  At least not in theory; in practice, I've had problems too.  (But of course, you should never start _or_ end a variable with an underscore, for reasons of readability.)

Comment: I usually end private variables with an underscore. I find them readable and I've had no problems up to now (`name_`, `value_`, `fragments_`, etc.).

Comment: It depends on the font, but with a lot of fonts, the underscore disappears.  As a general rule, using a leading or trailing underscore is very unfriendly to your readers.

Comment: I hadn't even considered the problem of the dissapearing underscore. I will think of an alternative for my personal coding convention :( ... Thanks.

Comment: I get an error for the initializing of the "R result{};" line: result has to be initialized by constructor and not with "{...}"

Comment: If you are using C++11, it should work (as long as you have a default constructor or R is a POD type). If you are not using a C++11 ompiler, replace the line with `R result = R();` (which still requires a default constructor or a POD type).

Comment: added -std=c++0x and this line goes through. However, I get the same error as above below: ambiguous overload of operator >>

Comment: Can you write just the `std::istringstream buffer{psMap[name]}; buffer >> result;` code without a function? If you cannot, then it's possible that you're trying to read a value that has no `>>` defined for it.